# Get nested values in one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm new to powershell so I had a simple question. Suppose I have the following powershell code:

```
$t = Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue
$t.SomeProperty.SomeNestedField
```

The second command above will print the value of `SomeNestedField`, which is nested inside `t`'s property called `someProperty`

**Can I combine these two lines into one powershell command (perhaps through piping), so that the output of the second command comes from just one command overall ?**

**Requirement is that it should print the value, not assign it to some powershell variable** ..

Perhaps something like:

`Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue | SomeProperty | SomeNestedField`

Some info that might help out:

Suppose I change above code to this:

```
$t = Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue
$u = $t.SomeProperty
$t.GetType()
$u.GetType()
```

When I execute `$t.GetType()`, the BaseType listed is a class, but if I do `$u.GetType()`, it's BaseType is listed as `System.ValueType`

Comment: You could do `(Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue).SomeProperty.SomeNestedField` OR `Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue | select -ExpandProperty SomeProperty`

Comment: Thanks! If you make an answer I can vote for it

Comment: OK thank you and will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` aka `SELECT-OBJECT`

```
Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue | select -ExpandProperty SomeProperty
```

Or `()`

```
(Get-SomeData -someParam someParamValue).SomeProperty.SomeNestedField
```